# Django Attribute Error - Form object has no attribute 'is_valid'

Tags: python, django

I am receiving an error, object has no attribute 'is_valid', when trying to insert form data into a form. Below is the structure of my code:

Views.py:

```
def add_user(request):
    form = Car(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        last_store = form.cleaned_data.get['value']
        make = request.POST.get('make', '')
        model = request.POST.get('model', '')
        ..

        car_obj = Car(last_store = last_store, make = make, model = model, series = series, series_year = series_year, price_new = price_new, engine_size = engine_size, fuel_system = fuel_system, tank_capacity = tank_capacity, power = power, seating_capacity = seating_capacity, standard_transmission = standard_transmission,  body_type = body_type, drive = drive, wheelbase = wheelbase, available = available)
        car_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/inventory/add/')
    else:
        form = Car()

    return render(request, 'cars/inventory-add.html', {})
```

Class:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    series_year = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    price_new = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    ..
    last_store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="last_store")
    available = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.make + " " + self.model)
```

CarForm (forms.py)

```
class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['last_store', 'make', 'model', 'series', 'series_year', 'price_new', 'engine_size', 'fuel_system', 'tank_capacity', 'power', 'seating_capacity', 'standard_transmission', 'body_type', 'drive', 'wheelbase', 'available']
```

The error lies within the `last_store` as without `form.is_valid()`, apparently I cannot use `form.cleaned_data`, but `form.is_valid()` seems to not even exist? As seen in the class, `last_store` is of type a foreign key, therefore I am struggling to set the default value for it when the user enters input into the form. The `last_store` variable is attempting to fetch the value from the inputted form data which consists of a SELECT option..

Answer (score 4):

You have a clash between your model and form, which are both named `Car`. Typically you would fix this by renaming the form `CarForm`.

Note that you shouldn't normally need to create the object with `car_obj = Car(...)`. If you use a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/), you can simplify your code to `car_obj = form.save()`. You should also move `CarForm(request.POST)` inside the `if request.method == 'POST'` check, and include `form` in the template context. Putting that together, you get something like:

```
def add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            car_obj = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/inventory/add/')
    else:
        form = CarForm()
    return render(request, 'cars/inventory-add.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: How could I create a model form? CarForm is currently undefined.

Comment: Please check updated code. It doesn't crash anymore which is sweet, but still not inserting into database. Could you see why this is? I'm not sure if my CarForm is correct or missing anything.

Comment: Try debugging by checking the values of `form.is_valid()` and `form.errors` in the view.

Comment: yes it is printing that the form is not valid. `The Car could not be created because the data didn't validate.`

Comment: Then check `form.errors` as I suggested, which will tell you why the data did not validate.

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py file line 2

```
form = Car(request.POST):
```

change it to

```
form = CarForm(request.POST):
```

Hope it works!